# stationary vs. undecimated wavelet transform

Tags: wavelet, wavelet-transform

I have a little bit confused on the difference between stationary wavelet transform and un-decimated wavelet transform.

So, can anyone tell me, if there is a difference between them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are the same (see [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stationary_wavelet_transform)). The *a trous* algorithm is the most efficient way to do this with typical short wavelet filters. See [this link](http://www.rug.nl/research/portal/files/2619332/2010SignProcWink.pdf) for its implementation in time and frequency domains.